# Data for v1 SSL CA certificate

Tags: java, ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate, mqtt

Using small java application that is trying to connect to MQTT Mosquitto server:

```
public class TestMQTT3 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Starting");

        String serverUrl = "ssl://192.168.1.8:8887";
        String path= "C:\\projects\\certs\\v1cert1\\";      


        String caFilePath =path+"ca.crt";

        String mqttUserName = "b";
        String mqttPassword = "b";

        MqttClient client;
        try {
            client = new MqttClient(serverUrl, "2");
            MqttConnectOptions options = new MqttConnectOptions();
            options.setUserName(mqttUserName);
            options.setPassword(mqttPassword.toCharArray());

            options.setConnectionTimeout(60);
            options.setKeepAliveInterval(60);
            options.setMqttVersion(MqttConnectOptions.MQTT_VERSION_3_1);


            //SSLSocketFactory socketFactory = getSocketFactory2(caFilePath,clientCrtFilePath, clientPKCS8KeyFilePath, "vlk32gm5");
            SSLSocketFactory socketFactory = getSocketFactory3(caFilePath);
            options.setSocketFactory(socketFactory);

            System.out.println("starting connect the server...");
            client.connect(options);
            System.out.println("connected!");
            Thread.sleep(1000);

            client.subscribe(
                    "/u/56ca327d17531d08e76bddd4a215e37f5fd6082f7442151c4d3f1d100a0ffd4e",
                    0);
            client.disconnect();
            System.out.println("disconnected!");


        } catch (MqttException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }



    private static SSLSocketFactory getSocketFactory3(final String caCrtFile) throws Exception 
    {
        Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());

        // load CA certificate
        X509Certificate caCert = null;

        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(caCrtFile);
        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
        CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");

        while (bis.available() > 0) 
        {
            caCert = (X509Certificate) cf.generateCertificate(bis);
            System.out.println(caCert.toString());
        }



        // CA certificate is used to authenticate server
        KeyStore caKs = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
        caKs.load(null, null);
        caKs.setCertificateEntry("ca-certificate", caCert);
        TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance("X509");
        tmf.init(caKs);


        // finally, create SSL socket factory
        SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.2");
        context.init(null, tmf.getTrustManagers(), null);

        return context.getSocketFactory();
    }


}
```

Got exception `no more data allowed for version 1 certificate`. Does it mean I have added too much while generating certificates? How to fix that?

Whole exception:

```
[
[
  Version: V1
  Subject: CN=192.168.1.8, O=KKK, L=London, ST=Some-State, C=EN
  Signature Algorithm: SHA256withRSA, OID = 1.2.840.113549.1.1.11

  Key:  Sun RSA public key, 2048 bits
  modulus: 22719559810083517491909000247132339461249719470652949862986827334901608600589679732441866997871147310866338850348308507945917576447555464822610703376220268171095737986004282342692433176036425215221660818545052652869581909689937776657975043908350238689319487771097966974817677894035239075257295777450253608248548795164791768001746409155638235628618974146122052642336965142533832882363992270778518206243586048144562512054071590298533267455082804212003487463538257377318690253962622465146752210606430933731401326048010743114828777989958366127133559917492234562152725553902506941299715458542263237882048715132459709162823
  public exponent: 65537
  Validity: [From: Mon Jan 13 19:52:59 EET 2020,
               To: Thu Jan 10 19:52:59 EET 2030]
  Issuer: CN=192.168.1.8, O=KKK, L=London, ST=Some-State, C=EN
  SerialNumber: [    de16bc63 b78467ee]

]
  Algorithm: [SHA256withRSA]
  Signature:
0000: 6C E8 E4 8C 66 ED 4D 2C   E7 7F 02 8D 59 AD 52 64  l...f.M,....Y.Rd
0010: 8C 11 80 38 F7 35 42 8B   A6 EB 4F D3 79 5B AF A8  ...8.5B...O.y[..
0020: CC 24 9D C8 1D 31 BC 89   CA CB 83 7B 77 93 41 73  .$...1......w.As
0030: 4A C7 8C DA 38 D1 1A DC   21 9A B6 F3 0F C4 AC 6D  J...8...!......m
0040: 03 1B 00 C9 B5 40 DE 32   12 D2 B1 66 7F 7B 1A 8F  .....@.2...f....
0050: FC E3 19 24 6B DE 31 3B   5E C0 07 6C B6 9C 67 07  ...$k.1;^..l..g.
0060: 14 19 61 58 2B C0 1B CF   B6 CB 10 6E 25 2C 85 66  ..aX+......n%,.f
0070: 61 54 1E 29 E2 24 0F 14   BB A5 21 AC 93 92 D6 2E  aT.).$....!.....
0080: 55 AF 80 5D DE A2 CE 70   D0 D7 F3 1C 9F 4F 07 05  U..]...p.....O..
0090: 15 71 C7 0C C8 5E B4 1B   87 65 68 30 26 3C EE 00  .q...^...eh0&<..
00A0: 05 1E CF E8 41 6B 17 31   9C A5 BE CD 15 E9 39 0E  ....Ak.1......9.
00B0: 90 92 97 ED A2 C5 F9 1C   21 9F 6A DF 36 53 4B 84  ........!.j.6SK.
00C0: A0 1F C7 99 36 BC 15 FA   10 84 C9 27 0A CE 9D F3  ....6......'....
00D0: D5 28 B3 D5 C0 72 DA CD   F2 0B 91 72 03 D3 48 48  .(...r.....r..HH
00E0: 78 75 C8 95 1F 03 C7 10   4D D1 60 C0 73 95 B9 9E  xu......M.`.s...
00F0: 90 3D F2 69 A6 9A AF 8B   95 DD 3F 18 C8 6A EE E1  .=.i......?..j..

]
adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: CN=192.168.1.8, O=KKK, L=London, ST=Some-State, C=EN
  Issuer:  CN=192.168.1.8, O=KKK, L=London, ST=Some-State, C=EN
  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0xde16bc63b78467ee
  Valid from Mon Jan 13 19:52:59 EET 2020 until Thu Jan 10 19:52:59 EET 2030

System property jdk.tls.client.cipherSuites is set to 'null'
System property jdk.tls.server.cipherSuites is set to 'null'
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_DH_anon_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_DH_anon_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_NULL_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: SSL_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: SSL_DHE_DSS_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_KRB5_WITH_DES_CBC_MD5
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_NULL_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: SSL_DH_anon_EXPORT_WITH_RC4_40_MD5
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: SSL_DH_anon_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_DH_anon_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_KRB5_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_KRB5_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_KRB5_EXPORT_WITH_DES_CBC_40_MD5
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_KRB5_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_MD5
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: SSL_DH_anon_WITH_RC4_128_MD5
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_NULL_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_NULL_SHA256
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: SSL_DH_anon_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_anon_WITH_NULL_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: SSL_DHE_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_anon_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_KRB5_EXPORT_WITH_RC4_40_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: SSL_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_KRB5_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_anon_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: SSL_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_RC4_40_MD5
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_KRB5_EXPORT_WITH_DES_CBC_40_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_KRB5_EXPORT_WITH_RC4_40_MD5
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_anon_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_KRB5_WITH_RC4_128_MD5
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_NULL_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_anon_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: SSL_DH_anon_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: SSL_RSA_WITH_NULL_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_DH_anon_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: SSL_RSA_WITH_NULL_MD5
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_DH_anon_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_DH_anon_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
trigger seeding of SecureRandom
done seeding SecureRandom
starting connect the server...
Allow unsafe renegotiation: false
Allow legacy hello messages: true
Is initial handshake: true
Is secure renegotiation: false
MQTT Con: 2, setSoTimeout(1000) called
MQTT Con: 2, setSoTimeout(60000) called
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
%% No cached client session
update handshake state: client_hello[1]
upcoming handshake states: server_hello[2]
*** ClientHello, TLSv1.2
RandomCookie:  GMT: 1578882131 bytes = { 57, 222, 150, 110, 156, 181, 223, 196, 49, 119, 224, 10, 49, 155, 71, 116, 198, 224, 188, 11, 171, 60, 141, 36, 81, 46, 19, 89 }
Session ID:  {}
Cipher Suites: [TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV]
Compression Methods:  { 0 }
Extension elliptic_curves, curve names: {secp256r1, secp384r1, secp521r1}
Extension ec_point_formats, formats: [uncompressed]
Extension signature_algorithms, signature_algorithms: SHA512withECDSA, SHA512withRSA, SHA384withECDSA, SHA384withRSA, SHA256withECDSA, SHA256withRSA, SHA256withDSA, SHA1withECDSA, SHA1withRSA, SHA1withDSA
Extension extended_master_secret
Extension server_name, server_name: [type=host_name (0), value=192.168.1.8]
***
MQTT Con: 2, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 199
MQTT Con: 2, READ: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 81
check handshake state: server_hello[2]
*** ServerHello, TLSv1.2
RandomCookie:  GMT: -817156553 bytes = { 175, 214, 119, 236, 117, 110, 42, 142, 130, 202, 231, 127, 145, 104, 168, 165, 214, 135, 240, 0, 215, 235, 60, 110, 181, 100, 164, 181 }
Session ID:  {9, 153, 67, 139, 84, 185, 224, 62, 87, 199, 169, 158, 226, 206, 196, 247, 4, 179, 239, 181, 48, 130, 249, 113, 252, 105, 139, 94, 134, 171, 186, 162}
Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Compression Method: 0
Extension renegotiation_info, renegotiated_connection: <empty>
***
%% Initialized:  [Session-1, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384]
** TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
update handshake state: server_hello[2]
upcoming handshake states: server certificate[11]
upcoming handshake states: certificate_request[13](optional)
upcoming handshake states: server_hello_done[14]
upcoming handshake states: client certificate[11](optional)
upcoming handshake states: client_key_exchange[16]
upcoming handshake states: certificate_verify[15](optional)
upcoming handshake states: client change_cipher_spec[-1]
upcoming handshake states: client finished[20]
upcoming handshake states: server change_cipher_spec[-1]
upcoming handshake states: server finished[20]
MQTT Con: 2, READ: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 1693
check handshake state: certificate[11]
MQTT Con: 2, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: no more data allowed for version 1 certificate
%% Invalidated:  [Session-1, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384]
MQTT Con: 2, SEND TLSv1.2 ALERT:  fatal, description = unexpected_message
MQTT Con: 2, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Alert, length = 2
MQTT Con: 2, called closeSocket()
MQTT Con: 2, called close()
MQTT Con: 2, called closeInternal(true)
MqttException (0) - javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: no more data allowed for version 1 certificate
    at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.ExceptionHelper.createMqttException(ExceptionHelper.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.ClientComms$ConnectBG.run(ClientComms.java:736)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: no more data allowed for version 1 certificate
    at sun.security.ssl.HandshakeMessage$CertificateMsg.<init>(HandshakeMessage.java:458)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:221)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:1037)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:965)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1064)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1367)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1395)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1379)
    at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.SSLNetworkModule.start(SSLNetworkModule.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.ClientComms$ConnectBG.run(ClientComms.java:722)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateParsingException: no more data allowed for version 1 certificate
    at sun.security.x509.X509CertInfo.parse(X509CertInfo.java:672)
    at sun.security.x509.X509CertInfo.<init>(X509CertInfo.java:167)
    at sun.security.x509.X509CertImpl.parse(X509CertImpl.java:1804)
    at sun.security.x509.X509CertImpl.<init>(X509CertImpl.java:195)
    at sun.security.provider.X509Factory.engineGenerateCertificate(X509Factory.java:104)
    at java.security.cert.CertificateFactory.generateCertificate(CertificateFactory.java:339)
    at sun.security.ssl.HandshakeMessage$CertificateMsg.<init>(HandshakeMessage.java:455)
    ... 10 more
```

Certificates V1 generation:

```
openssl genrsa -des3 -out ca.key 2048
openssl req -new -x509 -days 3650 -key ca.key -out ca.crt -config san_ca.cnf

openssl req -out server.csr -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout server.key -config san_server.cnf
openssl ca -config san_server.cnf -create_serial -batch -in server.csr -out server.crt

openssl req -out client.csr -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout client.key -config san_client.cnf
openssl ca -config san_client.cnf -create_serial -batch -in client.csr -out client.crt
```

Configuration files:

san_ca.cnf

```
[req]
default_bits       = 2048
distinguished_name = req_distinguished_name
req_extensions     = req_ext
prompt = no
[req_distinguished_name]
countryName                 =EN
stateOrProvinceName         = Some-State
localityName               = London
organizationName           = KKK
commonName                 = 192.168.1.8
[req_ext]
subjectAltName = @alt_names
[alt_names]
IP.1   = 192.168.1.8
DNS.1   = glass
```

san_server.cnf

```
[ca]
default_ca=CA_default

[CA_default]
dir=./ca
database=$dir/index.txt
new_certs_dir=$dir/newcerts
serial=$dir/serial
private_key=./ca.key
certificate=./ca.crt
default_days=3650
default_md=sha256
policy=policy_anything
copy_extensions=copyall

[policy_anything]
countryName=optional
stateOrProvinceName=optional
localityName=optional
organizationName=optional
organizationalUnitName=optional
commonName=optional
emailAddress=optional

[req]
prompt=no
distinguished_name=req_distinguished_name
req_extensions=v3_req
#x509_extensions=v3_ca

[req_distinguished_name]
countryName=EN
stateOrProvinceName=Some-State
localityName=London
organizationName=Internet Widgits Pty Ltd
commonName=192.168.1.8

[v3_req]
subjectAltName=@alt_names

[v3_ca]
subjectAltName=@alt_names

[alt_names]
IP.1=127.0.0.1
IP.2=192.168.1.8
DNS.1=localhost
```

ca.cer details:

```
Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 1 (0x0)
        Serial Number:
            de:16:bc:63:b7:84:67:ee
    Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
        Issuer: C=EN, ST=Some-State, L=London, O=KKK, CN=192.168.1.8
        Validity
            Not Before: Jan 13 17:52:59 2020 GMT
            Not After : Jan 10 17:52:59 2030 GMT
        Subject: C=EN, ST=Some-State, L=London, O=KKK, CN=192.168.1.8
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
                Public-Key: (2048 bit)
                Modulus:
                    00:b3:f9:3c:9b:86:2f:95:6c:45:6e:2d:98:69:c4:
                    39:4e:22:c4:f7:f1:b6:66:c4:59:d3:f5:bb:fb:f9:
                    3e:fc:a5:8b:07:9f:2f:f6:05:24:33:54:3b:50:3f:
                    96:40:69:40:68:85:b0:1c:43:65:d0:36:73:1f:cd:
                    3e:0b:6a:32:fe:95:4d:4c:be:cb:e9:04:44:d1:6f:
                    ab:79:da:48:28:06:cf:09:20:5b:04:69:ec:64:c8:
                    a9:3e:9e:e4:da:12:0d:04:da:63:3c:f8:55:c0:3a:
                    df:00:56:95:f7:d3:7d:1e:d5:de:d9:4c:ff:98:b5:
                    e9:98:5c:59:54:15:b5:b5:06:48:99:6f:db:1a:22:
                    1f:e5:9a:f4:fa:9e:b0:9f:6b:77:7b:a4:bc:45:ed:
                    10:ec:d0:a8:71:2f:77:e0:b8:16:9b:d1:9b:f7:6f:
                    22:db:f1:47:8e:4d:e7:18:cc:76:6b:ff:68:76:1f:
                    3a:80:c5:16:a9:71:ce:a2:2c:fa:4f:ec:f2:21:74:
                    a7:82:54:69:07:bb:0e:d9:d3:60:24:4b:67:fa:be:
                    f7:02:13:b1:90:b8:aa:86:d6:84:93:73:ee:66:b6:
                    45:29:9c:99:d0:6b:67:30:1a:b0:cf:af:99:51:ed:
                    9d:63:5f:d6:50:49:bc:f5:24:02:66:48:2f:2f:50:
                    e5:47
                Exponent: 65537 (0x10001)
    Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
         6c:e8:e4:8c:66:ed:4d:2c:e7:7f:02:8d:59:ad:52:64:8c:11:
         80:38:f7:35:42:8b:a6:eb:4f:d3:79:5b:af:a8:cc:24:9d:c8:
         1d:31:bc:89:ca:cb:83:7b:77:93:41:73:4a:c7:8c:da:38:d1:
         1a:dc:21:9a:b6:f3:0f:c4:ac:6d:03:1b:00:c9:b5:40:de:32:
         12:d2:b1:66:7f:7b:1a:8f:fc:e3:19:24:6b:de:31:3b:5e:c0:
         07:6c:b6:9c:67:07:14:19:61:58:2b:c0:1b:cf:b6:cb:10:6e:
         25:2c:85:66:61:54:1e:29:e2:24:0f:14:bb:a5:21:ac:93:92:
         d6:2e:55:af:80:5d:de:a2:ce:70:d0:d7:f3:1c:9f:4f:07:05:
         15:71:c7:0c:c8:5e:b4:1b:87:65:68:30:26:3c:ee:00:05:1e:
         cf:e8:41:6b:17:31:9c:a5:be:cd:15:e9:39:0e:90:92:97:ed:
         a2:c5:f9:1c:21:9f:6a:df:36:53:4b:84:a0:1f:c7:99:36:bc:
         15:fa:10:84:c9:27:0a:ce:9d:f3:d5:28:b3:d5:c0:72:da:cd:
         f2:0b:91:72:03:d3:48:48:78:75:c8:95:1f:03:c7:10:4d:d1:
         60:c0:73:95:b9:9e:90:3d:f2:69:a6:9a:af:8b:95:dd:3f:18:
         c8:6a:ee:e1
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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==
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Comment: Why do you want to use "v1" certificates? Have a look at https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5280#section-3.1  v1 certificates do not have extensions...

Comment: As I answered on [your previous question on security](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/224079/) you created a certificate that contains an extension (for SAN) but was wrongly marked as v1 due to an openssl bug. Only v3 certs are allowed to contain extension(s). If you want the extension, use the answer there to generate a v3 cert. If you truly want a v1 cert, remove the SAN extension, but then you can't use an IP address for the CommonName and have Java accept it, as you apparently wish to.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 I hope that Java will accept my my certificate without SAN when it will find it is V1 certificate